# convert a user inputted string into a value of the letter in a table

Tags: lua

i have a snippet of code here but i need help:
http://pastebin.com/7X4mBmLC

i use

```
local stringhex

repeat
    io.write("string:")
    io.flush()
    stringhex=io.read()
until stringhex
```

to get the user input and then i use the table
string2hexnocap
string2hexcap

to make it use those tables and the letters in the tables to have it printed like its hexidecimal.

but i dont know how to do the conversion of the string to hexidecimal. does anyone have a snippet that can help me?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
`function hex(s)
  return (s:gsub('.',function(a) return ('%2X'):format(a:byte()) end))
end`

Comment: @tonypdmtr - `('%02X'):format()` to correctly convert "\n" and "\t"

Comment: i havent actually tried much yet but tonypdmtr thats a bit too hard and not wat i was looking for really. i was searching for a function where if you do DissectString(stringhex) it would dissect the stringhex(the string user inputs which is read through stringhex=io.read() ) and it would see which letters are in and would create a line using the table like for instance i put in: hi it would dissect and see there is a letter h and  a letter i and would use the table to see what the value (or string) for that letter specificly is and would print that out so it would print the hex of the letters.

Comment: Then this maybe?
`for i = 1, #stringhex do
  i = stringhex:sub(i,i)
  io.write(string2hexcap[i] or string2hexnocap[i] or '')
end`